# Is direct connectivity between two containers possible (NIC to NIC)?

Tags: docker, virtualization, docker-network

### Assumption

Consider, two Docker containers `c1`,  `c2` created.

Each of them having Ethernet interfaces attached to network A:

- `c1_vnic_a`
- `c2_vnic_a`

Or they `c1`,  `c2` may have multiple Ethernet interfaces for different purposes.

These containers might be able to communicate with each other using any of the networks they are attached to. But I want to attach both of the containers to communicate directly without the involvement of any bridge network. An example that I want to experiment is a `D2D` link, considering the container `c1` as **device # 1** and `c2` as **device # 2**.

### Question

Is it possible to allow communication of two Docker containers without the involvement of any type of network bridge or `ovs`.

Comment: Containers don't have virtual NICs or a simulated network environment like what you're describing.  If you have a partial setup, or a specific problem with standard Docker networking you're trying to work around, can you edit the question to include these details?

Comment: @DavidMaze, Sorry for that. I had misconception of NICs being called as ethernet interfaces. Actually, I mean ethernet interfaces. I will edit the question again later. Thanks for the feedback!